# Функциональные интерфейсы: почему только один абстрактный  метод?

Tags: интерфейс, методы, java

Здравствуйте!
Почему функциональные интерфейсы могут содержать только один абстрактный метод? С чем это связано? И почему нельзя было сделать несколько методов (с разными параметрами) для взаимодействия с лямбда-выражениями в одном функ. интерфейсе?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Такое решение исходит из понятия функции. Формально функция имеет имя, список параметров и возвращаемое значение. Если функция имеет тоже имя и другой список параметров или другое возвращаемое значение, то это другая функция. Значит логично на одну функцию иметь один экземпляр интерфейса с одним методом (ведь функцию можно только применить, и ничего более).

В языке Java нет функций, как независимых сущностей, поэтому их эмулируют путем использования интерфейсов с одним абстрактным методом (Single Abstract Method, SAM).

Таким образом, если вы захотите определить функцию некоторого типа (Function, Consumer и т.д.), вам нужно лишь реализовать метод соответствующего интерфейса стандартным образом или с помощью синтакисиа определения лямбда-выражений. Во втором случае компилятор сможет принять решение о том, какого типа функциональный интерфейс нужно ипользовать (т.к. лямбда-функция - часто является параметром известного метода, а значит известного типа), и какой метод этого интерфейса в итоге нужно вызвать (это просто, т.к. он один).

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. 
Очень жаль, что не могу сделать так:

    @FunctionalInterface
    public interface SimpleInterface {
     void doSomething();
     void doSomething(String s);
    }

Выходит, если я хочу использовать комплекс разных лямбд-выражений, я должен плодить кучу интерфейсов. Как-то неудобно.

Comment: @javadranik, как и в случае с функциями, вам нужно определить кучу функций.

Comment: Да, но много методов в классе или интерфейсе ,на мой взгляд, это не так страшно как 100 примитивных интерфейсов в проекте. Такой вариант все равно кажется куда более удачным:

     Main main = new Main(new SimpleInterface() {

   @Override
   public void doSomething() {
    // РЕАЛИЗАЦИЯ
    
   }

   @Override
   public void doSomething(String s) {
    // РЕАЛИЗАЦИЯ
    
   }
      
  });

Comment: @javadranik, зачем вам 100 примитивных интерфейсов? Вам нужен один интерфейс на один тип функции. Тем более, что JDK уже предоставляет приличный набор функциональных интерфейсов (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/package-summary.html)