# Что значит "->" в Java?

Tags: java, лямбда-выражение

Изучаю [данный туториал](http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/java/). На некоторых скриншотах есть конструкция `->`, например:

```
vertx.deployVerticle("com.mycompany.MyOrderProcessorVerticle", res -> {
  if (res.succeeded()) {
    System.out.println("Deployment id is: " + res.result());
  } else {
    System.out.println("Deployment failed!");
  }
});
```

Не сталкивался раньше с таким. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что это такое и где можно об этом почитать хорошие материалы.

Comment: [Тыньк!](https://habrahabr.ru/post/224593/)

Comment: только в Java 8 и выше

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Это лямбда выражение - анонимная функция. Проще говоря, это метод без объявления *(без модификаторов доступа, возвращающие значение и имя)*.

Появились в 8 версии Java.

### Пример использования

Напишем простой пример *функционального интерфейса* :

```
public interface Lambda {
    //Метод интерфейса  с отсутсвующей реализацией
    int getDoubleValue(int val); 

    //Метод интерфейса с реализацией по-умолчанию
    default void printVal(int val) { 
        System.out.println(val);
    }
}
```

Функциональный интерфейс должен иметь только **один** абстрактный метод. Прочитать о причинах такого ограничения можно [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/357293/%D0%A4%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD-%D0%B0%D0%B1%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4).

Теперь создадим класс для использования

```
public class ClassForLambda {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Объявляем ссылку на функциональный интерфейс
        Lambda lam;
        //Параметр для нашего абстрактногго метода
        int num =9;

        //Прописываем первый вариант реализации
        lam = (val) ->  val * 2;
        System.out.println(lam.getDoubleValue(num));

        //Прописываем второй вариант реализации
        lam = (val) ->  {
            System.out.println("Your number is "+val);
            return val * 2;
        };
        System.out.println(lam.getDoubleValue(num));
    }
}
```

Как можно заметить, обращение к методу не изменилось. Изменению подверглась только реализация.

### Ссылки:

- [Хабр](https://habrahabr.ru/post/224593/)
- [JavaRush](http://info.javarush.ru/translation/2014/06/14/Lambda-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%85.html)
- [Еще один ответ на StackOverflow](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/408856/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%B1%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B2-java-8)